# Could we have a "remove all topics subscriptions" button in Rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am facing a lot the case where I start rviz with an old configuration and have to erase all my previous topic subscriptions one by one.

I know one can save and load configurations but having a simple button that would remove all the topic subscription (or the possibility to select several and remove them by pressing erase) would be a huge time-saver I think.

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9461/could-we-have-a-%22remove-all-topics-subscriptions%22-button-in-rviz?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Raph,

I can't test it right now but I think the function is already there.
At the bottom under your subscriptions click the "Manage" button, and then you will get a window with a "remove all" button.

---

Originally posted by [duststorm](https://answers.ros.org/users/301/duststorm/) with karma: 91 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-17**:
Ho I did not see that. is that new in diamondback? Thanks a lot!